# error in file handling in c++--no matching function for call to `std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(const char[8], bool)'

Tags: c++

I was trying out a file handling program to enter a record and in another program try to delete a record. I seem to be getting this error-

no matching function for call to `std::basic_fstream >::open(const char[8], bool)'

for every f.open statement which has an ios::binary declaration in it.

here are the codes

this one if for entering records

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>

class employee
{
      int code;
      char name[20];
      char desig[15];
      float salary;

      public: void get_emp();
};

void employee:: get_emp()
{
     cout<<"Code--> ";
     fflush(stdin);
     cin>>code;
     cout<<"Name--> ";
     fflush(stdin);
     gets(name);
     cout<<"Designation--> ";
     fflush(stdin);
     gets(desig);
     cout<<"Salary--> ";
     fflush(stdin);
     cin>>salary;
}

int main()
{
    fstream f;
    char ch;
    f.open("EMP.dat", ios::binary||ios::app);
    employee emp;
    cout<<"Enter data:\n";
    do
    {
                 emp.get_emp();
                 f.write((char*)&emp,sizeof(emp));
                 cout<<"Entre more???(y/n)";
                 cin>>ch;
    }while((ch=='y')||(ch=='Y'));
    f.close();
    system("pause>null");
    return 0;
}
```

this is for deleting record

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct employee
{
       int code;
       char name[20];
       char desig[15];
       float salary;
}emp;

int main()
{
    int xcode; //temporary declaration for employee code
    int flag = 0;
    fstream ef, tf; 
    //ef opened for reading, tf opened for transferring all records including modified      record 
    ef.open("EMP.dat", ios::binary|| ios::in);
    tf.open("TEMP.dat", ios::binary|| ios::out);
    cout<<"Enter employee code to delete:";
    cin>>xcode;
    while(ef)
    {
             if(!ef)
                exit(0);
             ef.read((char*)&emp, sizeof(emp));
             if(emp.code == xcode)
             {
                            flag = 1;
             }
             else
                tf.write((char*)&emp, sizeof(emp));
    }
    ef.close();
    tf.close();
    if(flag == 1)
       cout<<"Record deleted.";
    else
       cout<<"Not found.";
    fstream xf, yf;
    //tf opened for reading
    xf.open("TEMP.dat", ios::binary||ios::in);
    //ef opened for copying all records from TEMP.dat
    yf.open("EMP.dat",ios::binary||ios::out);
    while(xf)
    {
             if(!xf)
                exit(0);
             xf.read((char*)&emp, sizeof(emp));
             yf.write((char*)&emp, sizeof(emp));
    }
    xf.close();
    yf.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

please help. I need it for my exams.

Thank you

Comment: A simple typo: combine flags with bitwise `|` not logical `||`.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour and `gets` should never ever be used.

Answer (score 3):

Bitwise OR is a single pipe (|), not a double pipe.

Comment: But the open function syntax says we must use double pipe. (By the way, OR is double pipe).

Comment: @user3213658 Can you please share a link to that documentation? That is **not** true.

Comment: Which documentation  0x499602D2

Comment: @user3213658: Why do you think you need `||`? The "open function syntax" says nothing of the sort. That's the logical OR, which gives a result of `true` here since its operands are non-zero integers. You need bitwise OR, `|`, to combine the bits of the two operands to give the bitmask that `open` expects.

Comment: @CorvetteAB The fact of the matter is that the "double pipe" `||` symbol is a boolean operator (which is used for truth and false statements), while the single pipe `|` is a bitwise operator, the correct operator to use when specifying multiple open modes.

Comment: 0x499602D2 i found the error, you were correct, sorry. | is what is to be put, not ||. But there is one more problem. the program is working, but after i enter the records with the 1st code, and then i execute the 2nd code for deletion, and enter a record i want to delete(I have entered that record earlier), it says not found. Also, i go to my folder and open the EMP file to find it empty.

Comment: @CorvetteAB You should create another question which addresses this problem. Posting follow-up questions in the comments sections is not recommended.